# Error reporting while running under IIS

Tags: php, error-reporting

I am trying to get my install of PHP under IIS to display errors, but I'm having no luck at all.  I tried

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the script, and nothing shows up, just a blank screen.

I tried editing my PHP.ini file and setting

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Also tried

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = stdout
```

but nothing is showing up on the screen at all when my scripts throw errors.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that you're editing the PHP file in the correct location; IIS can look for a php.ini file in C:\WINDOWS rather than the install location of the PHP ISAPI or CGI module. Check the output of phpinfo(); to determine you're editing the correct php.ini file. Also, you need to restart the IIS service (or the computer overall) before those changes will be put into effect.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to resurrect a dead post but I had a similar issue and solved it by doing this in my PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This obviated the need to edit the server config and also allowed me to do this in just the method that I thought was problematic.

Comment: this is insufficient for the most important errors like parse errors

Comment: yeah it is :-)  I'm unlucky enough to be forced to use a Windows box as my test environment.  I catch parse errors on my local (Linux) dev box (or with my Eclipse editor if I'm lazy).

Comment: I'm not sure why some people say that this is insufficient for some error handling. The original question was to ask why errors were not being reported 'at all'. I find that this response is the correct way to enable reporting (although I chose to set the flag in the PHP.INI file, rather than scripting it). There are other settings which control the 'level' of reporting -- but again, this was not the point of the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps IIS is blocking your errors from displaying.
Try:

- Open inetmgr (Start -> Run -> inetmgr -> enter)
- click on the site
- select error pages (double click on it)
- on the right hand side click on “Edit Feture Settings”
- In the dialog that appears, select “Detailed Errors”.
- Save and close.
- Restart IIS just to be sure.

Posted for the sake of googlers like me.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot with my own issues

Comment: Thats helped me as well, Thanks

Answer (score -2):

[on php.ini in the php installation path change the value of error display to on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUZku.png)

Comment: please consider making use of the edit function and rewriting your answer. Explain how your answer helps and what the user will find when he clicks that link. don't make your whole answer be a link, that just makes it hard to read